# Schedule repetitive task daily

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, scheduled-tasks

I have an app where a user inserts an entry and saves it in sqlite database. This entry automatically saves the current date. When the entry is created I am able to get the number of days passed since the day the entry was entered. 
Now I need help on how I can schedule a task of querying the database daily at a specific time and display notifications when a certain number of days have passed. Your help will be gladly appreciated

Comment: Read about JobShedular and Jobservice.

Comment: Use Alarm manager to trigger the event at the specified time(register a broadcast receiver with alarm manager). Once the event is triggered then write your logic on Specified Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `JobDispatcher` more details are her https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

```
 Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        .setService(MyJobService.class)
        .setTag("my-recurring-tag")
        .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
        .setRecurring(true)
        .setReplaceCurrent(true)
        .build();
```